# Should I use a debug key or a release key while developing?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android app that uses Google Map API v2. I am currently developing the app. But I have a question in mind. I am currently using the debug key for development. I came to know that in order to publish the app to the play store I will require to sign my app with a release key. So is it possible to sign my app with a release key later ? Should I continue to develop with the debug key ?

Also can someone tell me how can I obtain a release key ? I have never published an app to the play store before.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html tells you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop your app using debug key. 
To obtain release key right click on your project you want to release -> Export -> Export Android Application-> Select your project if not selected -> Select create new keystore -> enter credentials -> Select place where you want to put release *.apk file

Do not forget your keystore password because it is impossible to restore it if it will be lost

Here illustrations how to create keystore on mac (this steps will be similar for other operating systems)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your app using debug key, but when you are going to release your app to the google play store at that time you have to use & sign your app with release key...

Follow below link to get release key.

[Get an Android certificate and the Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key)